# service.function is not a function error - angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular. I am using a service, `trelloService` which holds a function `getTaskData`. On `ng-click`, the controller's function `addme()` is called which then uses the `trelloservice.getTaskData` to get the data in order to display it on the page. But instead am getting this error.

Error:

```
TypeError: trelloService.getTaskData is not a function
    at Object.addme (scripts1.js:104)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:13231), <anonymous>:4:261)
    at f (angular.js:23371)
    at b.$eval (angular.js:15878)
    at b.$apply (angular.js:15978)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:23376)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12416
```

Js Code:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.service('trelloService', ['$http', '$q' ,function trelloService($http, $q) { 
    angular.extend(this, {getTaskData});            
    var deffered;

    function getTaskData(index, title) {
     deffered = $q.defer();
        config = {
            data: {
               //data here
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }
        $http.get('/api/task/create/1',config)
            .then((response) => {
               //
            })
            .catch((err) => {
            //
            })
        return deferred.promise;
    } 
    return getTaskData;
}])

.controller('parentcontroller', ['$compile','$http', 'trelloService' , function( $compile, $http, trelloService){
    'ngInject';    
    var vm = this;
    angular.extend(vm, {addme});    
    function addme(index){
       trelloService.getTaskData(index, vm.title)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("in then");
                vm.title = data.title;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            }) 
    }
```

Comment: Seems you've injected `trelloService` twice?

Comment: removed it. It was a typo when i was pasting the code here. Still getting the same error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function **getTaskData** bind from **this** object

```
.service('trelloService', ['$http', '$q' ,function trelloService($http, $q) { 

    var deffered;
    this.getTaskData = function(index, title) {
     deffered = $q.defer();
        config = {
            data: {
               //data here
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }
        $http.get('/api/task/create/1',config)
            .then((response) => {
               deffered.resolve(response);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
            deffered.reject(err);
            })
        return deffered.promise;
    } 
    }])
```

Comment: getting a new error: `angular.js:12416 ReferenceError: getTaskData is not defined`

Comment: delete **angular.extend(this, { getTaskData });** line see above code again

Comment: alright... thnx!! Now I am getting `ReferenceError: deferred is not defined` whereas I had already defined the variable in the service itself :(

Comment: @beginner do you tried to debug why it is undefined. :`return deferred.promise;` typo mistake here.

Comment: yes. I checked it. I had misspelled the variable at one place. Thankyou very much!!!!

Comment: you define **deffered** object but return **deferred** object. I edit above code now see